# Regexp to allow letters, numbers and -

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I have a problem with creating regexp to allow:

- exactly 2 letters at the beginning
- exactly 10 numbers after letters
- at most 4 "-" between numbers (should allow also without it)

so example of valid string is `GB123-55-22-22-6`,

my current regexp is: `/^([A-Z]{2})?[0-9]{10}$/`. He allow `GB1235522226` but I have a problem with "-".

can somoene tell me how to allow this regexp to use at most 4 "-" chars?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(?:[A-Z]{2})?(?=(?:-?\d){10}$)[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+){0,4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nGzSuc/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[A-Z]{2})?` - optional two letters
- `(?=(?:-?\d){10}$)` - there must be 10 digits optionally separated with a `-` till end of string, the string must end with a digit
- `[0-9]+` - one or more digits
- `(?:-[0-9]+){0,4}` - zero to four occurrences of a hyphen and then one or more digits
- `$`  - end of string.